# java: what is this method returning?

Tags: java

```
public class A extends B {
    private A(B b) {
        super(b);
    }

    public static A parse(string s) // question 1
    {
        B result = D.parse(s);

        return new A(result); // question 2
    }

}
```

**Question 1:** I don't understand what type of constructor(?) is this. 
What I think of a regular constructor looks something like `public A().` But this one:

```
public static A parse(string s)
```

How should I interpret it?

**Question 2:** `new A(result);`
What does this "new" do when returning something?
Is this method returning and calling a private constructor?

Comment: Why don't you try this out?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh other classes are extending B too. according to definition of BNF factory method   A := C | D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 1: It's not a *constructor* at all, it's just a static method that creates an object.

Question 2: `new` is used to call the constructor on a class. `new A(...)` calls the `A` constructor passing in the arguments.

So what you have there in `A` is a class that cannot be instantiated in the normal way (because the constructor is private), but from which you *can* get instances by calling `A.parse`. `parse` is usually called a "factory" method in this case.

Comment: Oh thank you very much!. So A parse()  is just a method that creates A's object?

Comment: @hibc: It creates `A` instances, yes (by calling the private constructor).

Answer (score 2):

It's not a constructor. It's a static method. And its return type is A, so it returns A.

```
return new A(result);
```

is equivalent to

```
A temp = new A(result);
return temp;
```

It calls the private constructor, which allows creating a new instance of A, and then returns this new instance.

What you have there is a typical factory method. Just like `Integer.valueOf(String)`, for example.